# logarithmic differences generator in R

Tags: r, logging

I was wondering how I can calculate the logarithmic difference of successive frequencies {I mean, Log(509)-Log(79),log(2240)-log(509) and etc} and graphs these logarithmic differences against interval midpoints in R.

```
   Frequency<-c(7,79,509,2240,2341,623,476,1230,1439,921,448,512,719,673,445,341,310,228,168,14)
    Interval<
    -c(7-8,8-9,9-10,10-11,11-12,12-13,13-14,14-15,15-16,16-17,17-18,18-19,19-20,20-21,21-22,22-23,23-24,24-25,25-26,26-27)

A<-data.frame(Interval,Frequency)
```

Comment: what do you mean by interval midpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Frequency <- c(7,79,509,2240,2341,623,476,1230,1439,921,448,512,719,673,445,341,310,228,168,14)
Interval <- c("7-8","8-9","9-10","10-11","11-12","12-13","13-14","14-15","15-16","16-17","17-18","18-19","19-20","20-21","21-22","22-23","23-24","24-25","25-26","26-27")
# inter <- seq(7.5, 26.5, 1)   
inter <- sapply( Interval, function( x ) {
  mean(as.numeric(unlist( strsplit( x, "-" ))))
})
freq_e <- diff( log( c( NA, Frequency ), base = exp( 1 ) ) )  # log base e
freq_10 <- diff( log( c( NA, Frequency ), base = 10 ) )       # log base 10

A <- data.frame( Interval = inter,
                 Frequency_e = freq_e, 
                 Frequency_10 = freq_10,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head( A )
#   Interval Frequency_e Frequency_10
# 1      7.5          NA           NA
# 2      8.5  2.42353770    1.0525291
# 3      9.5  1.86300016    0.8090907
# 4     10.5  1.48178313    0.6435302
# 5     11.5  0.04410232    0.0191534
# 6     12.5 -1.32378695   -0.5749134
```

Verify:

```
log(79) - log(7)
# [1] 2.423538
log(509) - log(79)
# [1] 1.863
```

Plot

```
plot(x = A$Interval, A$Frequency_e )
```

[image]

```
plot(x = A$Interval, A$Frequency_10 )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the comment. But I want to make a column including the log difference of successive frequencies, Log 79-Log 7, Log 509-log 79, Log 2240-Log 509 and etc.

Comment: the log difference corresponding to 7.5 must be empty because there is no data, say x, before 7.5 to do the log 7-log x. And also, is it log_{10} or log_e? that is, the entries in the frequency column should be shifted one level downwards